# Rewrite folder name from the URL in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi I am new to nginx and trying to remove folder name from the URL. 
Here is how my URL is accessible:

```
localhost/project_name/frontend/dashboard
localhost/project_name/frontend/feed
```

I want to remove the folder named 'frontend' from the URL. the folder contains all of my rendering templates. I have used following configuration but I get 404 when I enter the URL in browser after this configuration:

```
    location  /project_name/frontend {
     try_files $uri $uri/frontend /project_name/ @extensionless-php;
    }
```

I am not sure whether the configuration is correct, I have tried several configurations but none of them helps. 
P.S: This is my just first day on nginx, so pardon if I miss something very obvious.

Thank your for your help.

Comment: Does not work...Gives 404